# How to exclude a file when running git add

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have modified several files for debugging purposes.  I don't want to add them to `.gitignore` because they are valid files that need to be in the repo.  However, while debugging I need to make settings changes that I don't want to check in. Right now I am using `git restore --staged` after running `git add -all` to remove these files from my commit.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you don't have to `git add --all`.  You can `git add foo bar ...` to add files foo , bar.  You can also `git reset foo bar` after adding `foo` and `bar` to un-stage them for commit.

Comment: I would check in (commit) all those debug things. And then remove/drop the commits afterwards.